# this.state.events.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to read json in from and API. I am trying to map the events variable and display it in a h1 tag with the API  json field title, but I am getting the following error from the console "his.state.events.map is not a function" 
If anybody has any idea whats going on it would be great, I have been checking various resources on the internet and non of them work
Thanks in advance!!!

Heres some of the the json information i am getting back from the console from response

```
{…}
​count: 8
​next: null
​overflow: false
​previous: null
​results: Array(8) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      events: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchApi();
  }

  fetchApi() {
    fetch(
      "https://api.predicthq.com/v1/events/?q=sports&city=galway&country=IE",
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer 000000000000000000000000000000" // <---it's not this
        }
      }
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => console.log(response)); // <---when i add in this line
    // .then(response => this.setState({ 'events': response })) // <----and take out this one
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.events.map(function(event, index) { // <-----error here
            return <h1>{event.title}</h1>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: If `state.events` is not a function, then `response.json()` is not producing an array. Log out that value to see what transformation you need to do.

Comment: Can you log the value you're getting for `response` and update your question with that information?

Comment: I will update it now

Comment: I updated that, I hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to `response.results` to get an Array, then you can use map operator:

```
.then(response => this.setState({ 'events': response.results }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Access to response.results to get an Array, then you can use map operator:

.then(response => this.setState({ 'events': response.results }))